# Problema con SublimeREPL

Tags: python-3.8

tengo un problema, soy nuevo en esto y tengo un problema con Sublime text.
cuando pongo la REPL de Python me de el siguiente error:

```
                FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: 'Python")
```

ya probe haciendo un enlace simbólico ..
 # ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
pero no funciono..

gracias desde ya!

Comment: Mala mia! me di cuenta que estaba comentado el enlace simbolico, pero lo dejo por ahi le sirve a alguien.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía ese problema y no lograba resolverlo con el enlace simbólico ya que debía existir y claro no lo cambiaba. Tienes que editarlo con `-sfn`. Es decir:

```
ln -sfn /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
```

Espero que te funcione.